# How can I maintain an array, supporting random insertion and assignment, and querying the kth largest number in a given interval?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

**The problem is online**

Details: *The length of array <= 35000, the number of insertions <= 35000, the number of assignments <= 70000 and the number of queries <= 70000; time limit: 10s (Java:20s)*.

The vague solution I found online says that I need to maintain intervals using a scapegoat tree and in each node of the scapegoat tree, maintain a functional interval tree to query the `k`th largest element. I do know how to do the second step, but I don't know how to do the first one.

Comment: I don't know about scapegoat trees, but are you interested in a solution that uses segment trees or other trees?

Comment: Also, is the problem online or offline (must you execute each operation as it comes, or can you store them all first and then start processing them)?

Comment: This is not clear: "kth largest number in a given interval". Array elements of what type (integers?) what is "intervall"?

Comment: Also: If you specify a time limit: Should this run on a single CPU? How old is the machine?

Comment: @DrKoch Intergers. It means the subsequence [a,b). It's just an algorithm problem, given the range of inputs, one may expect an algorithm with complexity lower than O(n(logn)^2) would pass the tests

Comment: @DrKoch I mean O((logn)^2) for each operation

Comment: What range are your values in?

Comment: @IVlad the values in the array at any time would not exceed 70000(no idea why the problem picks this number)

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose that we have (semantically) an array like

```
0: 31337
1: 42
2: 314159
3: 9000
4: 100   .
```

We have a scapegoat tree where the array entries are ordered by index. Each node of the tree stores the number of left-descendants so that we can search efficiently by index. (This makes the scapegoat implementation simpler too.)

```
               9000(3)
              /       \
         42(1)         100(0)
        /     \
31337(0)       314159(0)
```

For each subtree, we also maintain a value-ordered BST of values that it contains. This BST can be a scapegoat tree and also has left-descendant counts for implementing selection.

```
31337: {31337}
42: {42, 31337, 314159}
314159: {314159}
9000: {42, 100, 9000, 31337, 314159}
100: {100}
```

To insert, we insert into the scapegoat tree, updating the left-descendant counts and inserting the new value into the BSTs as we walk down. The amortized insertion cost is O(log^2 n) if we reconstitute the BSTs in linear time (proof: each value belongs to O(log n) BSTs, so scapegoating is O(log n) per node touched, for a total of O(log^2 n); inserting into O(log n) BSTs above the scapegoated node is O(log^2 n)). To update, we have to delete/insert from the BSTs (O(log^2 n)).

The query path is where things get ugly. Identifying the O(log n) BSTs and singleton sets whose union is the array section is the easy part. The hard part is actually doing the selection. Binary search will yield O(log^3 n)-time queries, because we have O(log n) rounds of selecting in O(log n) arrays, each with a selection cost of O(log n). Perhaps the Frederickson--Johnson algorithm points to an answer, but it's complicated even for arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

The basic key to performance in such cases is a data structure (aka collection) which supports the required operations with O(log n) complexity (or better).

In your case you need insertions and lookups (called assignments and queries in your question).

Because you also ask for "largest" you need a *sorted* collection. (This rules out collections based on Hashes which have O(1) complexity)

So you should start with binary trees or tries.

It is currently impossible to give more details because your answer is too vague.